# My 5 year old got suspended for insubordination. This is his 2nd suspension how can I better help him

Tags: toddler

School just started and already my kindergartner has been suspended twice. This time it's for insubordination. He is only 5. How can I better help him with his behavior?

His behavior at home is not great he will not listen to anyone. The school says he hits and punches the teacher but doesn't hit or punches me or my mom. I tried talking to the principal but I just feel like it's a no go there not trying to help at all.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit on the insubordination?

Comment: What is his behavior like at home? how do you make him obey? We need more details!

Comment: I think the problem is with the school not the kid, suspending a 5 year old for insubordination is an absolutely crazy policy. Maybe for violence or constant disruption i could understand, but insubordination!?. Could you move the child to a school that isn't so draconian ?

Comment: Could you give us some details about what exactly his behavior is in school?  Is he refusing to listen to the teacher or is he deliberately trying to undermine her/his authority  ;)

Comment: @cballard What was your kindergartner suspended for last time?

Comment: Inappropriate behavior

Answer (score 1):

**Consequences**

If he is attacking other kids or even his teacher, the director is choosing the lesser of two evils.

In home you need to sit with your brother and tell him that you love him, and that you want to help him, explain him, that his reaction was scary for everyone and you want to know what happend.

Ask him how "WE" can avoid that the same situation repeat, give him ideas. Tell him that is okay to feel anger/sadness/frustration and teach him other venues to release this feelings.

Don't expect a quick change but every situation take it as an oportunity to enforce the idea of thinking before reacting.

For you, just tons of patience, and keep repeating over and over and over, kids are really smart just support him with every little improvement.